# Can't install/use allegro

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, allegro, allegro5

So, I've been working on programming a small game using allegro5. I'm currently in college, so my professor gave us some kind of "base project" on Visual Studio that already had allegro in it. The problem is, that when I run the program from Visual Studio, everything works fine! But if I run it from the created .exe it doesn't, because it can't find the allegro5 libraries.

So, how can I fix this? How do I properly install allegro5 so I can run it directly from the .exe?

Comment: it probably depends on DLLs that it can't find when you run the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ways below:

1. The simplest way: Copy the needed DLLs to the same folder as the `exe` you are running is located.
2. Add the path where the dll is located to the system environment variable, or put the dll in the directory specified by the system environment variable. For example: `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: Hi, @Fio
may I know if your problem has been solved?